# Check if mp3 file is in given directory

Tags: python, operating-system, mp3, listdir

I can't see what i am doing wrong here

```
import os

def check():
    path = "d://Mu$ic//"
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith("*.mp3"):
            print (os.path.join(path,file))

check()
```

The output doesn't show up , any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: try `file.endswith('.mp3')`

Comment: Yup that's what i need , **Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting the `*` should work, since `endswith` matches on a string suffix (as opposed to `*.mp3` which is a wildcard):

`file.endswith(".mp3"):`

Also, you could replace `//` with just `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Is only mp3 files in the folder? If so why do you need the check for endswith? If mp3 is the only file type in that folder it should be able to return them without checking if they end with .mp3. Unless you have other file types in there then you would need the endswith check. I did your code here without endswith and it returned every .wav file in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3, you also can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

```
import glob

_path = '{0}**/*.mp3'.format("d://Mu$ic//")
file_lst = glob.glob(_path, recursive=True)
print(file_lst)

['2.mp3', '3.mp3', ...]
```